# Icon into a ButtonField

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to insert the icon trash from `Bootstrap` but I can't, so I don't know if that is possible.

The only thing that I can insert was the class of the `Button`

`<asp:buttonfield  buttontype="button" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Details" commandname="Delete" />`

So, does someone knows how can I put the `Glyphicon` of trash? I'm using the `Button` into a `GridView`

[How my button looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNhIU.png)

[How I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDbK7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridTest">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Trash 
                </button>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I know how to put the icon into a normal button, but this time I'm trying to put into a button, that is into a GridView :/

Comment: I understand, try this.